# How to cover sortmethod in code coverage (angular)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, code-coverage

I have a file called `sorting.helper.ts` where my sort methods are written:

[image: enter image one description here]
[image: enter image two description here]

Then I called the methods in another file.
So how can I make the code coverage of the two files in the .spec?

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { SortingHelper } from "../../helpers";

 describe('SortingHelperComponent', () => {

     it('should compare numbers', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
   });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should write separate unit tests for that method to keep everything as simple as possible.

So if you have `numberSort` function you need to create at least 3 unit tests that will cover all the paths in your's function

1. `n1 > n2`
2. `n1 < n2`
3. `n1 = n2`

If you create such 3 test cases you will cover the function in 100%

How ever beware of code line coverage it is not always a good metric

Comment: I am actually hanging int the test writing. Do you have an idea, on how i cam implemented it?

Comment: Can you share the code